# How to manipulate dataframe to count values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How would I go about turning this DF:

```py
          id          message_id           author_id            guild_id  has_attachments          channel_id              created_at
37438  37439  702588325613011054  599221212010512394  322850917248663552  0                 520132129103806483      2020-04-22 18:35:10.286 
37439  37440  702588325969657876  470642155824873472  322850917248663552  0                 373594756116119572      2020-04-22 18:35:10.371 
37440  37441  702588327467024474  371187008971866114  322850917248663552  0                 362236453771804683      2020-04-22 18:35:10.728 
37441  37442  702588328029061150  284428586981523466  322850917248663552  0                 338017726394138624      2020-04-22 18:35:10.862 
37442  37443  702588328368930876  382261028051877889  322850917248663552  0                 338017726394138624      2020-04-22 18:35:10.943
```

into something like this:

```py
          author_id     channel_id
guild_id  [sum/count]  [sum/count]
```

I assume the columns would be author_id raw and channel_id raw, but how would I go about this?

I want to insert this dataframe per row (guild) into influxdb

Comment: `df.groupby('guild_id').count()`?

Comment: Do you really want a column per author and another set of columns per channel? That is a lot of columns. You probably want to pivot to a longer form first.

Comment: I guess maybe the design may be wrong here...I'm trying to insert each row as a row inside influxdb to track usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
df.groupby('guild_id')['author_id']['channel_id'].sum()
df.groupby('guild_id')['author_id']['channel_id'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code for sum the columns:

```
df[[col1, col2, etc]].sum()
```

and for counting:

```
df[[col1, col2, etc]].count()
```

or

```
[df[col].value_counts() for col in [col1, col2, etc]]
```

depends what you want to do.